# Add value to array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

I have class named as `login` (without encapsulate fields, I just want to make it simple)

```
public class login
{
    String username;
    String password;

    public login(String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

DisplayList.java

```
public class DisplayList extends ListActivity
{
    login[] values;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String username, password;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < somelength)
        {
            username = somestring;
            password = somestring;

            values[count] = new login(username, password);

            //if I Toast it
            //Toast.makeText(this, username + " . " + password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            count++;
        }

        login_adapter = new login_adapter(this, values);
        setListAdapter(login_adapter);
    }
}
```

I want to pass values (**login[]values**) to login_adapter (**class login_adapter extends ArrayAdapter**)

but I always come with NullPointerException on "**values[count] = new login(username, password);**"

if I Toast it "**Toast.makeText(this, username + " . " + password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**" the Toast come with all values.

Comment: `values = new login[4];` array initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `somelength` to initialize your array ,because you are traversing in loop equal to the size of `somelength` and creating an object of `login` every time so

```
public class DisplayList extends ListActivity
{
    login[] values;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String username, password;
        int count = 0;

        values = new longin[somelength];
        // ^^^^   initialize your array 

        while (count < somelength)
        {
            username = somestring;
            password = somestring;
            values[count] = new login(username, password);
            count++;
        }
        login_adapter = new login_adapter(this, values);
        // make sure the login_adapter class name and object name is different            
        setListAdapter(login_adapter);
    }
}
```

For convention you can rename classes to `login` => `Login` ,`login_adapter`=> `LoginAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your array.
You need something like this at start of onCreate:

```
values = new login[2];
```

Note that for convention class names must start with uppercase carachter.

I suggest you to use ArrayList so you don't need to know array length at creation time